# PyScripter: Where is %APPDATA%\pyScripter\skins folder located in disk?

Tags: windows-7, python, themes, ide

I have PyScripter installed from the executable file downloaded from their website. 
But the white background is just burning up my eyes so I wanted to change the theme. I googled upon how to change the theme, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Its located at `%APPDATA%\pyScriptor\skins` of course.  Just navigate to that folder by using `Windows Explorer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt and run

```
echo %APPDATA%
```

mine comes back with "C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming"

You can also open Windows Explorer and enter %APPDATA% as the folder address and it will show the correct location.